# Problem booting Ubuntu with wubi on windows 10

Tags: boot

I downloaded and installed Ubuntu with wubi it installed successfully but when I restarted my PC it started as windows 10 and no option to start Ubuntu what to do now?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you used the **UEFI** version of `wubi`, so you won't have an 
option to boot Ubuntu *automatically*.

You have to enter the **UEFI boot menu** of your PC and chose Ubuntu manually.

This is taken from [here](https://www.lifewire.com/wubi-linux-installation-program-2201175):

```
How To Boot Into Ubuntu

The UEFI version of WUBI installs Ubuntu to the UEFI boot menu which means by
default you won't see it when you boot your computer.

Your computer will instead continue to boot into Windows and it will appear that
nothing has in fact happened.
To boot into Ubuntu restart your computer and press the function key to pull up 
your UEFI boot menu.
```

Comment: I tried pressing those keys nothing happened, btw how can I fix it now?

Comment: @MohmmedAdil please check with the manual of your PC on how to enter UEFI boot menu.

Comment: Thank you brother I'm not good with tech so haha I'll figure it out. thank you very much but I have a question. Can I use windows after starting it in UEFI???